# Two parallel tcolorbox tables

Tags: multicol, tcolorbox

I tried to place two parallel tcolorbox tables in part of a page:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\tcbuselibrary{skins}
\usepackage{multicol}


%mytable constuction:
\tcbset
{
    ponyotab/.style=
    {
         enhanced,
         fonttitle=\bfseries,
         fontupper=\normalsize\sffamily‍‍,
         colback=white!,
         colframe=black!65!white,
         colbacktitle=gray!20!white,
         coltitle=black,center title
    }
}
\newtcolorbox{mytable}[3][]
{
     ponyotab,
     tabular*={\arrayrulecolor{black}\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.0}}{#2},% change 1.0  to change cell heights
     title=table \ref{#3},
     before={\begin{table}[htb]\refstepcounter{table}\label{#3}\centering},
     after={\end{table}},
     #1
}


\makeatletter
\tcbset
    {
tabular*/.style 2 args={%
    boxsep=0pt,top=0pt,bottom=0pt,leftupper=0pt,rightupper=0pt,
    toptitle=1mm,bottomtitle=1mm,boxrule=0.5mm,hbox,
    before upper={\def\arraystretch{1.1}#1%
    \tcb@hack@currenvir\tabular{#2}},
    after upper=\endtabular\arrayrulecolor{black}},
    }
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{2}

\begin{mytable}{c|c}{kk}
group & one      \\\hline
red   & 1000.00  \\\hline
green & 2000.00  \\\hline
blue  & 3000.00  \\\hline
sum   & 6000.00 
\end{mytable}


\begin{mytable}{c|c}{jj}
group & one      \\\hline
red   & 1000.00  \\\hline
green & 2000.00  \\\hline
blue  & 3000.00  \\\hline
sum   & 6000.00 
\end{mytable}

\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

But I failed. Is there a way to do this with multicols or other tools?

I prefer to keep mytable environment command unchanged.

Comment: The problem is probably the `before={\begin{table}[htb]` and `after={\end{table}}` getting stuffed into a multicolumn environment. Do you want the tables to float or not?  I probably also wouldn't use multicolumn at all, but something like the `minipage` environment.

Comment: I tried minipage but it failed for me.

Comment: Did you do my first suggestion? Also, you need to use the key `nobeforefafter`. (And then the `minipage` environment is probably unneeded.)

Comment: Well I don't know how to change the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably -- or do you? -- don't want to float the environment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\tcbuselibrary{skins}
\usepackage{multicol}


%mytable constuction:
\tcbset
{
    ponyotab/.style=
    {
         enhanced,
         fonttitle=\bfseries,
         fontupper=\normalsize\sffamily‍‍,
         colback=white!,
         colframe=black!65!white,
         colbacktitle=gray!20!white,
         coltitle=black,center title
    }
}
\newtcolorbox{mytable}[3][]
{
     ponyotab,
     tabular*={\arrayrulecolor{black}\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.0}}{#2},% change 1.0  to change cell heights
     title=table \ref{#3},
%     before={\begin{table}[htb]\refstepcounter{table}\label{#3}\centering},
%     after={\end{table}},
     nobeforeafter, % <-- added
     #1
}


\makeatletter
\tcbset
    {
tabular*/.style 2 args={%
    boxsep=0pt,top=0pt,bottom=0pt,leftupper=0pt,rightupper=0pt,
    toptitle=1mm,bottomtitle=1mm,boxrule=0.5mm,hbox,
    before upper={\def\arraystretch{1.1}#1%
    \tcb@hack@currenvir\tabular{#2}},
    after upper=\endtabular\arrayrulecolor{black}},
    }
\makeatother

\begin{document}

% \begin{multicols}{2}

\noindent
\begin{mytable}{c|c}{kk}
group & one      \\\hline
red   & 1000.00  \\\hline
green & 2000.00  \\\hline
blue  & 3000.00  \\\hline
sum   & 6000.00
\end{mytable}
%
\quad
%
\begin{mytable}{c|c}{jj}
group & one      \\\hline
red   & 1000.00  \\\hline
green & 2000.00  \\\hline
blue  & 3000.00  \\\hline
sum   & 6000.00
\end{mytable}

%\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

**Revised answer:** If you don't want to change the `mytable` environment, then one easy way is to wrap your tables in a command like the below `\ccolumns` command. You can be lazy about spurious spaces because of the `nobeforeafter` key from `tcolorbox`, though it's probably a good habit to be more careful anyway.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\tcbuselibrary{skins}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{lipsum}


%mytable constuction:
\tcbset
{
    ponyotab/.style=
    {
         enhanced,
         fonttitle=\bfseries,
         fontupper=\normalsize\sffamily‍‍,
         colback=white!,
         colframe=black!65!white,
         colbacktitle=gray!20!white,
         coltitle=black,center title
    }
}
\newtcolorbox{mytable}[3][]
{
     ponyotab,
     tabular*={\arrayrulecolor{black}\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.0}}{#2},% change 1.0  to change cell heights
     title=table \ref{#3},
%     before={\begin{table}[htb]\refstepcounter{table}\label{#3}\centering},
%     after={\end{table}},
     nobeforeafter, % <-- added
     #1
}


\makeatletter
\tcbset
    {
tabular*/.style 2 args={%
    boxsep=0pt,top=0pt,bottom=0pt,leftupper=0pt,rightupper=0pt,
    toptitle=1mm,bottomtitle=1mm,boxrule=0.5mm,hbox,
    before upper={\def\arraystretch{1.1}#1%
    \tcb@hack@currenvir\tabular{#2}},
    after upper=\endtabular\arrayrulecolor{black}},
    }
\makeatother

\newcommand{\ccolumns}[2]%
  {\par\noindent
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}%
      \begin{center}#1\end{center}\end{minipage}
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}%
      \begin{center}#2\end{center}\end{minipage}
}

\begin{document}

% \begin{multicols}{2}
\lipsum

\noindent
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
\begin{center}
\begin{mytable}{c|c}{kk}
group & one      \\\hline
red   & 1000.00  \\\hline
green & 2000.00  \\\hline
blue  & 3000.00  \\\hline
sum   & 6000.00
\end{mytable}
%
\end{center}
\end{minipage}
%
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
\begin{center}
%
\begin{mytable}{c|c}{jj}
group & one      \\\hline
red   & 1000.00  \\\hline
green & 2000.00  \\\hline
blue  & 3000.00  \\\hline
sum   & 6000.00
\end{mytable}
\end{center}
\end{minipage}

% \end{multicols}

\ccolumns{
\begin{mytable}{c|c}{kk}
group & one      \\\hline
red   & 1000.00  \\\hline
green & 2000.00  \\\hline
blue  & 3000.00  \\\hline
sum   & 6000.00
\end{mytable}

}{

\begin{mytable}{c|c}{jj}
group & one      \\\hline
red   & 1000.00  \\\hline
green & 2000.00  \\\hline
blue  & 3000.00  \\\hline
sum   & 6000.00
\end{mytable}

}

\end{document}
```

Comment: but I want each table be in the center of each half page. As if they are in two columns.

Comment: @user62181 -- Do you mean the centre of each "column" where the dividing line of the two columns is itself the centre of the textblock?

Comment: Yes, if I understand your  words correctly.

Comment: Thanks. But still there is a problem. The commented out line used to add table number. How can I restore the Table number?

Comment: @user62181 -- Try this: `\newtcolorbox[auto counter]{mytable}[3][]{ ponyotab, tabular*={\arrayrulecolor{black}\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.0}}{#2}, title={table \thetcbcounter}, nobeforeafter, #1 }` in place of the original definition. I think your way was overly complicated.

Comment: It works. But it not a normal counter as before. It ignores chapters,etc. And there not a label to refer to.

Comment: @user62181 -- `\newtcolorbox[auto counter, number within=section]{mytable}[3][]{ ponyotab, tabular*={\arrayrulecolor{black}\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.0}}{#2}, title={table \thetcbcounter}, label=#3, nobeforeafter, #1 }`

Answer (score 1):

My final code:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\tcbuselibrary{skins}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{lipsum}

%table
%mytable constuction:
\tcbset
{
    ponyotab/.style=
    {
         enhanced,
         fonttitle=\bfseries,
         fontupper=\normalsize\sffamily,
         colback=white!,
         colframe=black!65!white,
         colbacktitle=gray!20!white,
         coltitle=black,center title
    }
}
\makeatletter
\tcbset
    {
tabular*/.style 2 args={%
    boxsep=0pt,top=0pt,bottom=0pt,leftupper=0pt,rightupper=0pt,
    toptitle=1mm,bottomtitle=1mm,boxrule=0.5mm,hbox,
    before upper={\def\arraystretch{1.1}#1%
    \tcb@hack@currenvir\tabular{#2}},
    after upper=\endtabular\arrayrulecolor{black}},
    }
\makeatother

\newtcolorbox[auto counter,number within=chapter]{ptable}[3][]
{
     ponyotab,
     tabular*={\arrayrulecolor{black}\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.0}}{#2},% change 1.0  to change cell heights
     title=Table \ref{#3},
     label=#3,
%     before={\begin{table}[htb]\refstepcounter{table}\label{#3}\centering},
%     after={\end{table}},
     nobeforeafter, % <-- added
     #1
}

\makeatletter


\newcommand{\twocols}[2]%
  {\par\noindent
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}%
      \begin{center}#1\end{center}\end{minipage}
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}%
      \begin{center}#2\end{center}\end{minipage}
}

\newcommand{\onecol}[1]%
  {\par\noindent
    \begin{minipage}[t]{\textwidth}%
      \begin{center}#1\end{center}\end{minipage}
}

\def\btable#1#2#3\ntable
{
    \onecol
    {
        \begin{ptable}{#1}{#2}
        #3
        \end{ptable}
    }
}
%end table second type





\begin{document}

\chapter{oo}
\btable{c|c}{jj}
group & one      \\\hline
red   & 1000.00  \\\hline
green & 2000.00  \\\hline
blue  & 3000.00  \\\hline
sum   & 6000.00
\ntable

% \end{multicols}

\twocols
{
\btable{c|c}{kk}
group & one      \\\hline
red   & 1000.00  \\\hline
green & 2000.00  \\\hline
blue  & 3000.00  \\\hline
sum   & 6000.00
\ntable
}
{
\btable{c|c}{jj}
group & one      \\\hline
red   & 1000.00  \\\hline
green & 2000.00  \\\hline
blue  & 3000.00  \\\hline
sum   & 6000.00
\ntable
}

\end{document}
```

[image]